# adding a simple fragment to android app

Tags: android, android-fragments

im new to android, and i'm tryigng to add a simple fragment (that holds a listview) to the main activity.

is the fragment suppose to be inside the MainActivity?

i have checked, and most of the problems, and the solutions here looked like it was a version problem (using android.support.app.v4.Fragment), but it doesn't looks like it here.
im pretty sure it's something simple that im missing.

Thanks!

```
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.app.Fragment;    
import android.app.FragmentManager;    
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.ViewGroup;    
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;    
import android.widget.ListView;    

import java.util.ArrayList;    

public class MainActivity extends Activity{    

   @Override    
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();    
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();    
           PlaceholderFragment phf = new PlaceholderFragment();    
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, phf);    
           fragmentTransaction.commit();       

   }    

   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {    

           public PlaceholderFragment() {    

           }    

           @Override    
           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg,    
                                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
               View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, vg);    

                   ArrayList<String> tempDataArr = new ArrayList<>();    
                   tempDataArr.add("TEMP 1");    
                   tempDataArr.add("TEMP 2");    
                   ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_fnf,R.id.list_item_fnf_textview,tempDataArr);    
                   ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_fnf);    
                   listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);    
               return rootView;    

           }    
       }    
}
```

Comment: How does your layout file look like?

Comment: This is more of a hunch, but you may want to try altering your `inflate` call to `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, vg, false);`

Comment: ok. it was stupid. i forgot to add <Fragment> to the main XML.